# Clear cells within a range

Tags: excel, vba

I am having a issue clearing the contents in a range with a custom button I created in the ribbon. The button works fine, calls the function but only cell "A6" clears, nothing else. I have searched and searched and tried multiple other variations with the same results each time. Here are only a few of the attempts.

```
Function ClearSheet()

    Worksheets("Template").Range("A6, I100000").ClearContents

End Function


Function ClearSheet()

    Worksheets("Template").Range("A6, I100000").Clear

End Function

Function ClearSheet()

   With Worksheets("Template")
        .Range("A6, I100000").ClearContents
   End With

End Function

Function ClearSheet()
Dim Rng as Range
Rng  = Worksheets("Template").Range("A6, I100000")

    Rng.ClearContents

End Function

Function ClearSheet()

    Worksheets("Template").Range("A6, I100000").Value = ""

End Function
```

And a hundred others, What am I missing please help!!

Comment: `Rng  = Worksheets("Template").Range("A6, I100000")` would need to be `Set Rng  = Worksheets("Template").Range("A6:I100000")` -- although there is little point of setting a range variable if you will only use it in a single line of code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the proper usage of range is:

`Range("A6:I100000").ClearContents`

Comment: Lol, I have been tearing my hair out for a couple hour, I guess we all have are blonde moments, Thank you.